# BeautifulSoup How do I extract data from specific columns from HTML table. My code is extracting all the columns

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML table with a row and some columns.  I would like to extract the data from the column which has the text "Total" and the data from the column which has the value "93"
Just these 2 columns I would like to extract the data.  My code is extracting the data from all of the columns.

E.g. My output is:

```
Total
93
93
0
0
```

My desired output would be:

```
Total 93
```

My code is:

```
def extract_total_from_report_htmltestrunner(): 
    filename = (
    r"C:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test\TestReport\ClearCore_Automated_GUI_Regression_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename, 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    tr_total_row = soup.find('tr', {'id': 'total_row'})
    tr_total_row.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    print tr_total_row.text
    return tr_total_row.text
```

The HTML snippet is:

```
<table id='result_table'>
    <tr id='total_row'>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>93</td>
        <td>93</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do extract "Total" "93" and print it out in the same line?

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_all()` and *slice* the results:

```
" ".join(td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr_total_row.find_all("td")[:2])
```

Comment: That's great.  Thanks for your help.